# listView.setOnClickListner not working

Tags: listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I implemented onClickListener to a listview like this but no toast showing up anything wrong with this code? anyother way to implement clickListners on listviews?

```
    public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment{

    String[] drawerList = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

    public DrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false);

        List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(drawerList));
        ArrayAdapter<String> listItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.drawer_list_item, listItems);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        listView.setAdapter(listItemsAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(drawerList));
```

**With:**

```
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(drawerList));
```

**Replace:**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.drawer_list_item, listItems);
```

**With**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.id.drawer_list_item, listItems);
```

Comment: hi thanks for response.but String is not necessary.my problem was actually i did not give enough height to list item to listen a click.it was solved after incresing height